# Arrow locale not working

Tags: python, datetime, python-arrow

```
arrow.get(datetime.now(), 'Asia/Shanghai').date()
```

Returns `datetime.date(2017, 3, 26)` but it is 27th March there. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quickstart) gives example over starting with utc then applying the timezone. For your case:

```
import arrow
utc = arrow.utcnow()
utc.to('Asia/Shanghai').date()
```

should give you the local date you are looking for.